# SGS3 I-9300 Android 4.2 - why can't I disable these system apps?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, security, vpn, nfc, java

*nb. I can disable them using 3rd party root apps without any discernible negative effects.*

[image] [image]

Are these networking protocols default? They seem to be harmless but everything I read about sit0 seems to suggest it's no longer used.

[image]

This looks like some serious networking issues to my layman's eye. Yes or no?

[image: Logcat Extreme]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

I have 100s or 1000s of logcat messages where a request for Neighboring Cell IDs is denied. Is this some kind of worm attempt being blocked by policy?

[image: Logcat 2]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: The last image, is the Radio event log **RILJ** which is Radio Interface Layer - methinks there's some jumping to wrong conclusions... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why" is not a question well suited for our site, as it probably is a *speculative question* and such off topic (see our [FAQ]). Although, a short technical explanation: The company building your ROM decided such.

"How can I disable them" would be better fitting, and even has answers:

If you cannot disable them from *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*, you will ***need to root*** your device. Having done that, there are several apps available allowing you to "freeze" unwanted system apps. The most well-known of them is [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) which, as a side-effect, provides you with a powerful backup solution. Another candidate for that is [App Quarantine ROOT/FREEZE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.appquarantine).